# TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService without file index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av, react-native-track-player

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sggpS.png)

My react native project does not have an index.js file to be able to register registerPlaybackService, I only have an App.js file

I searched a lot and found a way to add the index.js file and change the entryPoint

Answer (score 1):

I don't use an index.js. React.native.track.player works fine for me in app.js having the registration there.

I developed using expo dev client.
I have the later RNTP rc.
I have built for both play store and App Store.
I use remote (Bluetooth) controls.

I too was concerned because of what the documentation said.